# how to get the result of a request to format it in the query_builder option of the symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, doctrine-query

I have a request that retrieves the departments of a user that I display in a select tag the problem is that the result I like to format it and change it here is my request:

```
'query_builder' => function(UserRepository $user_repository){
                $x = $user_repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where('u.department != \'\' ')
                    ->andWhere('u.department != 1 ')
                    ->andWhere('u.statut= \'Actif\' ')
                    ->andWhere('u.type = 30')
                    ->andWhere('u.supprimer = 0')
                    ;
                dump($x);
                return $x;
            },
            'choice_label' => 'department',
```

and the result is displayed as follows:

```
["59"]
["69"]
["77,33"]
```

I want to format it so that I can display it in its entirety as follows:

```
59
69
77
33
```

thank you for your help

Comment: How is that possible that a part of your result is formatted in a way, and another part is formatted differently ?

Comment: I assume that if a user has more than one department, it's separated by comma, isn't it?

Comment: yes @D.Dimitrov if the user has several departments, we do the separation by a comma

Comment: @Cid  that's what I found in the data bse and I can't change the values because it can affect the code

Comment: It's not the best way to handle data like that. Better edit the database and entire code...

Comment: I agree with @D.Dimitrov This is possible, but this can be very tricky. Doctrine can be pretty subborn when you change the content of entities. This is better to fix a badly designed database and the application instead of patching around. The longer you'll wait for it, the harder it will become to do that.